# Why we need to implement certain methods when we extend classes in android?

Tags: java, android, abstract-class

> Even if they are going to be empty.

for example oncreate method.

When we write extends "some class name",a warning is shown that certain methods have to be implemented.

Comment: read this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are [abstract](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html) classes/methods and need to be overridden. You can choose to override the functionality or just let it do what the parent classs  is doing.

> An abstract class is a class that is declared abstract—it may or may
>   not include abstract methods. Abstract classes cannot be instantiated,
>   but they can be subclassed.
>
> An abstract method is a method that is declared without an
>   implementation (without braces, and followed by a semicolon), like
>   this:
>
> `abstract void moveTo(double deltaX, double deltaY);`
>
> If a class
>   includes abstract methods, then the class itself must be declared
>   abstract, as in:
>
> ```
> public abstract class GraphicObject {
>    // declare fields
>    // declare nonabstract methods
>    abstract void draw();
> }
> ```
>
> When an abstract class is subclassed, the subclass usually provides
>   implementations for all of the abstract methods in its parent class.
>   However, if it does not, then the subclass must also be declared
>   abstract.